# Entity Framework Share Queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I don't quite know how to word this, so I'm just going to explain my scenario.

I have a scenario where I have a `TerminationDate` field on an `EmploymentHistory` table that can be null, or a date in the future.  `EmploymentHistory` joins to an `Employees` table and it's a 1:M relationship, where a single `Employee` can have multiple `EmploymentHistory` records.  That `Employees` table joins to a lot of different places such as a `Users` table that represents the front end portal the `Employees` can log in to.

I frequently need to grab only the active employees.  The SQL logic for being active is `WHERE TerminationDate IS NULL OR TerminationDate >= GETDATE()`.  So if TerminationDate is null or if it's set in the future.

So in EF I have these queries like this:

`// Grab all Active Employees
context.Employees.Where(e => e.EmploymentHistory.Any(eh => eh.TerminationDate == null || eh.TerminationDate >= DateTime.Today).ToList();`

`// Get all Users 
context.Users.Where(u => u.Employee.EmploymentHistory.Any(eh => eh.TerminationDate == null || eh.TerminationDate >= DateTime.Today).ToList();`

etc

This logic shows up in about 5 different places.  How do I share the `EmploymentHistory.Any(eh => eh.TerminationDate == null || eh.TerminationDate >= DateTime.Today` part of the logic when the base nav prop may be different?  Tried playing with `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` but got no where other than I think I have a solution if I can make all the Entities that need this inherit from a Base and could always assume there's a nav prop called Employee sitting there and the Base is my `T`.  If I try an extension method, EF Core can only evaluate it client side, not server side.

Comment: you have two Options, Store the Expression, the base expression and replace the input parameter based on the Expression you are calling.  Or alternatively you can just store the IQueryable to employees, and when you want to get the users call the employees queryable, and then add a selectMany(e => e.Users)

Answer (score 3):

You could write an expression for the `EmploymentHistory`: `Expression<Func<EmploymentHistory, bool>> activeEmployee = eh => eh.TerminationDate == null || eh.TerminationDate >= DateTime.Today;`

And use it like so: 
`context.Employees.Where(e => e.EmploymentHistory.Any(activeEmployee)).ToList();` 
and 
`context.Users.Where(u => u.Employee.EmploymentHistory.Any(activeEmployee)).ToList();`.

It's not a huge reduction in code, but a lot less typing, and even better if you need to change the logic for some reason and don't want to change it everywhere is shows up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Wesker.  This is the kind of thing I was looking for.  Unfortunately, it doesn't look like this works with EF Core.  EF Core requires a Func<EmploymentHistory, bool> and then when I do that I get a NotSupportedException: The given arguments did not match the expected arguments: Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.  Looks like it's a bug in EF Core -  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8019

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this.  Using SQL Server and EF you could

1. Create a function in SQL and import it into EF.  It's a little tricky, but it can be done.
2. Create a View on the server that does the computation and define the relationships in EF so that you can call from the view and greedy load the information that you need from there.
3. Add a computed column to the table to show whether the user is active or not.
4. Add a materialized column to the table to track whether or not the user is active and maintain that column in addition to the existing data.

I tried option one in an older version of EF and it took forever to work through it.  The performance wasn't great and I never tried it again.  It looks like this has gotten easier in newer versions of EF though, so you're welcome to give it a try.

Option 2 probably offers the best balance of performance and accuracy since you can optimize the query for the view and then still greedy load the data for best efficiency.

Option 3 works a lot like option 2 and makes for the simplest C# code, but it's not going to be quite as efficient since it will have to handle the columns individually rather than in aggregate.

There are times that I've found you have to use materialized information and it does offer the absolute best performance since there's no added calculation at runtime.  You risk your data being out of sync though, so I would reserve it for only the most severe cases where that performance is critical.

Answer (score 1):

The bug that @Rounder referenced in his comment on @WeskerTyrant 's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104865/entity-framework-share-queries#comment83188847_48105092) has now been [resolved](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8019#issuecomment-375445140) in EF Core.

So, you can do something like this:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> IsActiveEmployee =
    eh => eh.TerminationDate == null ||
          eh.TerminationDate >= DateTime.Today
```

And then call it like:

```
context.Users.AsQueryable().Where(IsActiveEmployee).ToList();
```

Notice the addition of the `.AsQueryable()` that allows the `.Where()` to accept an `Expression`.